# Connect the Dots

Tags: code-golf, string, ascii-art

Given a series of `o`s representing dots, connect them vertically or horizontally

### Examples

Input:

```
o   o

o
```

Output:

```
o---o
|
|
o
```

---

Input:

```
o   o    o

    o
```

Output:

```
o---o----o
    |
    o
```

### Spec

- If you want the input padded with spaces to form a rectangle, please specify this in your answer
- There will only be `o`, spaces, and newlines in the input
- There will always be a pair of dots to connect
- No two `o`s will be directly adjacent
- Dots should be connected with `|` and `-`, for vertical and horizontal connections respectively
- No dot connections will overlap

Comment: Do you have to connect every legal pair or just connect the dots into 1 component? Can the dots always be connected into 1 component? "There will always be at least *two dots* to connect" would make more sense if I understand it right. A couple test cases could clear these up too.

Comment: @randomra you have t connect every legal pair, they won't always be 1 component

Comment: @Downgoat How about some more test cases that cover disconnected components and loops within a single component then? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Japt, <s>33</s> 29 bytes

```
Uy eV="o +o"_rS'|} y eV,_rS'-
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VXkgZVY9Im8gK28iX3JTJ3x9IHkgZVYsX3JTJy0=&input=Im8gICBvICAgIG8KCiAgICBvIg==)

#### How it works

```
Uy         // Transpose rows with columns in the input.
eV="o +o"  // Set V to the regex-string "o +o", and recursively replace each match Z with:
_rS'|}     //  Z with spaces replaced with "|"s.
y          // Transpose again.
eV,        // Recursively replace matches Z of V with:
_rS'-      //  Z with spaces replaced with "-"s.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <s>137</s> 133 bytes

```
->s{eval"s.split($/).map(&:chars)#{".map{|x|x.join.gsub(/o +(?=o)/){|x|x.tr' ',?|}.chars}.transpose"*2}.map(&:join)*$/".sub'?|','?-'}
```

This is absolutely horrible. Still trying to golf.

Input as a padded rectangle, please.

Newline for "readability":

```
eval"s.split($/).map(&:chars)#{".map{|x|x.join.gsub(/o +(?=o)/){|x|x.tr' ',?|}
.chars}.transpose"*2}.map(&:join)*$/".sub'?|','?-'
```

Comment: Alright, I'll input as a padded rectangle, but only because you asked so nicely.

Comment: Can you use `\b` instead of `(?=o)`?

Comment: @Justin Doesn't appear to work. :/

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina/), 80 bytes

```
T` `-`o.+o
Tm` `|`(?<=(?(1)!)^(?<-1>.)*o\D*¶(.)*) (?=(.)*¶\D*o(?<-2>.)*$(?(2)!))
```

Input needs to be padded.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=VGAgYC1gby4rbwpUbWAgYHxgKD88PSg_KDEpISleKD88LTE-Likqb1xEKsK2KC4pKikgKD89KC4pKsK2XEQqbyg_PC0yPi4pKiQoPygyKSEpKQ&input=ICAgIG8gICAgIAogICAgICAgICAgCm8gICBvICAgIG8KICAgICAgICAgIAogICAgbyAgbyAgCiAgICAgICAgICAKICAgICAgICAgIApvICAgICAgICBv)

#### Explanation

The first stage is pretty simple, it just turns all spaces into hyphens which are found between two `o`s in the same line.

The second stage covers the `|`s. This is a bit trickier and requires [balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406/1633117). The lookbehind

```
(?<=(?(1)!)^(?<-1>.)*o\D*¶(.)*)
```

checks that there's an `o` earlier in the same column. Remember that lookbehinds should be read from right to left. `(.)*` stores the horizontal position of match, `\D*¶` checks skips to any character in the preceding lines, `o` matches literally. Then `(?(1)!)^(?<-1>.)*` ensures that the horizontal position of that `o` is the same.

The lookahead

```
(?=(.)*¶\D*o(?<-2>.)*$(?(2)!))
```

Does exactly the same thing in the opposite direction.